# почему файл html и css не связываються хотя я все сделал правильно

Tags: html, css, notepad++

```
    <link href="newfilecs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="newfile/css"/>
```

Comment: Проверьте путь к файлу и правильность написания link - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newfilecs.css">`

Comment: Вы можете пользоваться Sublime Text 3, в нём есть плагин AutoFileName, который будет подсказывать какой файл выбрать в src или href, таким образом вы не запутаетесь, не будете руками прописывать путь, а также пользоваться Emmet, чтобы всё нужное за вас подставлялось

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="newfilecs.css" type="text/css">
```

http://htmlbook.ru/html/link